# Running DNX (EF7) database migration on Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, database-migration, dnx, entity-framework-core

I've been running a MVC project with ASP.NET 4.6 and EF7 locally and everything works fine. I ran the dnx . ef migration Initial commands to create the database tables, and everything ran fine. The app works.

With Azure I have one problem, I can't seem to run the dnx . ef migration command so my SQL database is empty. I've debugged Startup.cs and the connection string is correctly retrieved, but the tables are not there.

I used the Publish option in Visual Studio 2015 to deploy to my Azure Web App.

How can I run this command on my web app? Is there another way to generate the database?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have it in front of me, but I believe in the publish options, there's a "run EF migrations on publish". Did you see that?

Comment: There is no such option at least in Visual Studio 2015, EF7, DNX Beta 5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that the EF team has eliminated the infamous database initializers and offers a more versatile method for that on version 7.

Just use these methods in the pipeline before any call to the database,

```
yourDbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

to create the database in case it doesn't exists and

```
yourDbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

to apply migrations (if you use this feature later). Both methods above also have an asynchronous version.

In my solution I have created an static class that I use to initialize the database and seed it with some data. I call the Seed method from the Configure method in the Startup class when some condition is met.

Comment: Looks like the `.Migrate` command has been (re)moved. Anyone know what to do now?

Comment: Julie Lerman, a well known name in the EF space has written an article.  Looks like they've done away with auto migrations in EF 7.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt614250.aspx

Comment: That being said I'm able to use Database.Migrate from the constructor of my DbContext.